# How to resolve Tkinter problem in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have problem when I try to make youtube downloader using python or tkinter in python.

code is :

```py
path_style=ttk.Style
path_style.configure("PT.TButton",background="DarkOrange1",foreground="DarkOrange1", font = ("bahnschrift SewiBold",10))
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baraa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\folder\baraa.py", line 33, in <module>
    path_style.configure("PT.TButton",background="DarkOrange1",foreground="DarkOrange1",
TypeError: configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'style'
```

Comment: `ttk.Style` needs to be `ttk.Style()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried instantiating the style class like so using the parentheses:

```
path_style=ttk.Style()
```